# Extraer valores XML en nuevas lineas

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

Tengo la siguiente estructura en XML y me gustaría extraer dos valores en concreto. "mac" e "ip"
El formato es el siguiente:

```
..
    <entry>
      <ip>192.168.1.1</ip>
      <mac>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac>
      <ttl>60</ttl>
      <interface>abc</interface>
      <port>1</port>
    </entry>
..
```

Cual es la forma más optima para transformar el resultado en diferentes lineas:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00 192.168.1.1
```

Ejecuto el siguiente formato, pero unicamente me muestra la mac

```
sed '/<ip>/,/<\/ip>/d;/<mac>/!d;s/ *<\/\?mac> *//g' file.xml
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: sed '/<ip>/,/<\/ip>/d;/<mac>/!d;s/ *<\/\?mac> *//g' file.xml
pero me muestra unicamente la MAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mejor usar una herramienta específica como xmllint:

```
xmllint --xpath "//entry/ip/text()" fichero.xml
```

Esto busca el elemento `<ip>` dentro de `<entry>` e imprime su valor.

---

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero.xml
 <entry>
      <ip>192.168.1.1</ip>
      <mac>00:00:00:00:00:00</mac>
      <ttl>60</ttl>
      <interface>abc</interface>
      <port>1</port>
    </entry>

$ xmllint --xpath "//entry/mac/text()" fichero.xml
00:00:00:00:00:00

$ xmllint --xpath "//entry/ip/text()" fichero.xml
192.168.1.1
```

Comment: gracias! pero en formato "mac ip" (en la misma linea) ?

Comment: puedes recoger el resultado de ambas y luego imprimirlo

Comment: no es posible con un mismo comando extraerlo?

Comment: no que yo sepa.

Answer (score 0):

***Para imprimir ip y mac, puede realizarse de esta manera:***

```
$echo 'cat //entry/\*[self::**ip**|self::**mac**]' | xmllint --shell "fichero.xml" | tr -d '<>ip/mac-' | grep -v "^[[:blank:]]\*$"
```

192.168.1.1

00:00:00:00:00:00