# Extraer texto entre dos campos en un archivo XML con sed

Tags: linux, xml, shell, sed

Tengo un archivo XML con bastantes registros del que paso a poner la primera entrada:

```
<meps>
   <mep>
     <fullName>Magdalena ADAMOWICZ</fullName>
     <country>Poland</country>
     <politicalGroup>
     Group of the European People's Party (Christian Democrats)
     </politicalGroup>
     <id>197490</id>
     <nationalPoliticalGroup>Independent</nationalPoliticalGroup>
  </mep>
<mep>
```

Me gustaría extraer todos los registros que se encuentran entre el campo "politicalGroup" mediante `sed`, es decir, `Group of the European People's Party (Christian Democrats)` en el ejemplo que puse.

En el post [Using sed to extract text between 2 tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98217/using-sed-to-extract-text-between-2-tags) he visto que se utiliza el siguiente comando para extraer texto entre dos etiquetas. Lo adapto a mi fichero:

```
sed -n 's:.*<politicalGroup>\(.*\)</politicalGroup>.*:\1:p' fichero
```

Al utilizar el comando he conseguido imprimir por pantalla el campo deseado pero solamente un registro, cuando me gustaría poder extraer todos los registros del fichero. ¿Se podría modificar algo del código para poder extraer todas las líneas que estén entre ambas etiquetas?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Parsear un XML con sed es bastante frágil, apostaría por usar algún parser de verdar como xmllint ([véase un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/370461/83)) o un lenguaje de más alto nivel como Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando un poco más he conseguido utilizar otro código diferente que me ha servido:

`cat fichero | tr "<" "\n" | sed -n '/politicalGroup>./p' | sed 's/politicalGroup>//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

Así he conseguido imprimir por pantalla todos los registros y mediante los comandos `sort, uniq` he conseguido contar los valores repetidos del fichero.